# Facing issues while create Sharepoint lists with lookups columns using xml

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling, elements-xml

I want to create two list 1) Employee details and 2) Selected Employee programatiocally using XML in SPFx.

So, I have created two files for each list 1) element.xml and 2) Schema.xml. And added that files in package-solution.json.

1. Employee details List

Below is the code of empdetails_element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

        <Field ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300A7}"
                Name="EName"
                DisplayName="Employee Name"
                Type="Text"
                Required="FALSE"
                Group="SPFx Employee Columns" />

        <Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB28}"
                Name="EAge"
                DisplayName="Employee Age"
                Type="Number"
                Required="FALSE"
                Group="SPFx Employee Columns">
        </Field>

        <ContentType ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C7A"
                Name="Employee"
                Group="SPFx Employee Content Types"
                Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
                <FieldRefs>
                        <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300A7}" />
                        <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB28}" />
                </FieldRefs>
        </ContentType>

        <ListInstance
                Id="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC306R9}"
                CustomSchema="empdetails_schema.xml"
                FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
                Title="Employee List"
                Description="Employee List"
                TemplateType="100"
                Url="Lists/EmployeeList">
        </ListInstance>

</Elements>
```

Below is the code of empdetails_scheme.xml

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Basic List" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Basic List" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <MetaData>
      <ContentTypes>
        <ContentTypeRef ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C7A" />
      </ContentTypes>
      <Fields></Fields>
      <Views>
        <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
          <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
          <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
          <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
          <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
          <ViewFields>
            <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
            <FieldRef Name="EName"></FieldRef>
            <FieldRef Name="EAge"></FieldRef>
          </ViewFields>
          <Query>
            <OrderBy>
              <FieldRef Name="ID" />
            </OrderBy>
          </Query>
        </View>
      </Views>
      <Forms>
        <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
        <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
        <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      </Forms>
    </MetaData>
  </List>
```

Now, I am creating second list "Selected Employee" which have lookup columns of first list.

1. Selected Employee

Below is the code of selectedEmp_element.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

        <Field ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC307A5}"
                Name="EName"
                DisplayName="Employee Name"
                Type="Lookup"
                Required="FALSE"
                List="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC306R9}"
                ShowField="Title"
                Group="SPFx EMP Columns" />

        <Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECA19}"
                Name="ECity"
                DisplayName="Employee City"
                Type="Text"
                Required="FALSE"
                Group="SPFx EMP Columns">
        </Field>

        <ContentType ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675A7U"
                Name="Emp Cost Center"
                Group="SPFx Emp Content Types"
                Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
                <FieldRefs>
                        <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC307A5}" />
                        <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECA19}" />
                </FieldRefs>
        </ContentType>

        <ListInstance
                Id="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC306R8}"
                CustomSchema="selectedEmployee_schema.xml"
                FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"
                Title="Selected Employee List"
                Description="Selected Employee List"
                TemplateType="100"
                Url="Lists/SelectedEmployee">
        </ListInstance>

</Elements>
```

Below is the code of selectedEmployee_schema.xml

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Basic List" EnableContentTypes="TRUE" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Basic List" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentTypeRef ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675A7U" />
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields></Fields>
    <Views>
      <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="EName"></FieldRef>
          <FieldRef Name="ECity"></FieldRef>
        </ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="ID" />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

After that i am adding this in "package-solution.json".

```
"features": [
      {
        "title": "list-demo Feature",
        "description": "The feature that activates elements of the list-demo solution.",
        "id": "c121150d-50e3-4897-ab10-43855070d303",
        "version": "1.0.0.16",
        "assets": {
          "elementManifests": [            
            "./emp/empdetails_element.xml",
            "./semp/selectedEmp_element.xml"
          ],
          "elementFiles":[            
            "./emp/empdetails_scheme.xml",
            "./semp/selectedEmployee_schema.xml"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

So, while installing my app in site at that time list will created.

But, I am facing the issues it's give me a below error. "**value does not fall within the expected range**"

I want to create list while installing app in my site content.